# Xamarin Android Player Crash Showing Error "Arguments cannot be null"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-android-player

I am using beta version of xamarin android player 0.6.5 , it was running fine but suddenly it is not opening showing error **"An unhandled exception has occurred, Argument cannot be null, Parameter name: source"**. I have uninstalled xap and download and reinstall but on opening it is still showing the same error. I have seen through xamarin blogs i have seen one post of this but no one replied to that post. I am glad if anyone has overcome this problem.

Comment: the Xamarin Android Player is no longer supported.

Comment: Really ?? can you give me the source of your information. Is there any alternative of XAP?

Comment: There is a blog post about it from Miguel, although I can't find it at the moment.  The Google stock emulators are much more performant now; VS2015 has it's own emulator, or you can use Genymotion

Comment: The blog is here: https://blog.xamarin.com/live-from-dotnetconf-cycle-7-xamarin-studio-6-and-more/ and the note of deprecation is here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/#Emulator_Choices